# Where can I find the Tomcat 7 installation folder on Linux AMI in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: linux, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a elastic beanstalk linux-tomcat ami instance with the sample application installed and working off the public dns. I'm able to ssh into the
 instance but cannot find where tomcat 7 lives (ie. the conf directory to edit server.xml). I've tried this with a 64 and 32 bit ami. Any ideas on where I might find this? I looked under:

```
/etc
/usr/share
```

I did find a `elasticbeanstalk-tomcat7-deployment` file under `tmp` (was empty).

I did a:

```
sudo yum install tomcat7
```

and the sample application is also being served up from `:8080` and working on the public DNS. So I (think) have 2 tomcat servers running on the same beanstalk instance. In that case, I'm trying to find where the Tomcat 7 folders are (serving pages on port `80`).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Since late 2012, it is usually under `/usr/share/tomcat7`.

Prior to that, it was usually found under `/opt/tomcat7`.

Comment: This was the location on Amazon Linux AMI older than late 2012 - the location has since changed.

Comment: I found it on `/usr/share/tomcat7`, at Ubuntu, late 2015! ;)

Comment: Currently in mid-2016 using tomcat8 `/usr/share/tomcat8`

Comment: May 2019: /var/lib/tomcat8

Answer (score 56):

Not sure if this would be helpful. I am using a similar Amazon Linux AMI, which has tomcat7 living under /usr/share/tomcat7.

If tomcat is already running on your machine you can try:

```
ps -ef | grep tomcat
```

or

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

to check where it's running from.

Answer (score 23):

- If you want to find the webapp folder, it may be over here:

> **/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/**

- But you also can type this to find it:

> **find / -name 'tomcat_version' -type d**

Answer (score 11):

Use "whereis" command.

> **$ whereis tomcat8** 
>  tomcat8: /usr/sbin/tomcat8 /etc/tomcat8
>   /usr/libexec/tomcat8 /usr/share/tomcat8

Answer (score 8):

As of October 3, 2012, a new "Elastic Beanstalk for Java with Apache Tomcat 7" Linux x64 AMI deployed with the Sample Application has the install here:

```
/etc/tomcat7/
```

The /etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf file has the following settings:

```
# Where your java installation lives
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jre"

# Where your tomcat installation lives
CATALINA_BASE="/usr/share/tomcat7"
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat7"
JASPER_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat7"
CATALINA_TMPDIR="/var/cache/tomcat7/temp"
```

Comment: This shows that tomcat is in /usr/share/tomcat7. /etc/tomcat7 just has the tomcat7.conf file.

Answer (score 4):

Following environment variables worked for me on Debian Wheezy 7 and Tomcat 7:

```
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat7
CATALINA_TMPDIR=/tmp/tomcat7
```

(I did create /tmp/tomcat7 manually)

Answer (score 2):

As of 6-6-15 the Web Root location is at /tmp/deployment/application/ROOT using Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

My server is CentOS 7, and I install tomcat by:

```
sudo yum install tomcat
sudo yum install tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps
```

I found my webapps folders in:

```
/usr/share/tomcat/
```

and

```
/var/lib/tomcat/
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Ubuntu 16.04 server, and default tomcat installation it's under:

```
/var/lib/tomcat8
```