# Tomcat 10 pass Environment Variable or Property to spring boot context

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties, spring-context, tomcat10

Well, I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application in a tomcat 10 server, passing a one environment key. I need to pass de "secret" of jasypt for decode the passwords in my application, but I can't do this because the context don't run the same as the spring boot application normally.

In my `App.java` with main loos like

```java
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(App.class);
      }
    
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        setProp();
        final SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(AppBatch.class);
        application.run(args);
      }

    private static void setProp() throws Exception {
        // Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        // Context envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        // String propertyKey = (String) envCtx.lookup("jasypt.encriptor.password");
        String propertyKey = System.getProperty("jasypt.encriptor.password");
        Properties props = new Properties(System.getProperties());
        if (propertyKey != null && !propertyKey.isEmpty()) {
          props.setProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password", propertyKey);
          System.setProperties(props);
        } else {
          throw new Exception("Not setted property in jasypt password");
        }
    }

}
```

This code works with an application runs in a normally deploy with Spring Boot, with the

```
java -jar -Djasypt.encryptor.password="secret" app.jar ...
```

The code commented is that I tried with tomcat but don't work, the application starts even before that this code, I can't see any log, even this log was in the method configure. But in the tomcat 10, this approach don't work. I need to pass this secret like a property or with the environment. How can I do?

Comment: `encriptor`? You sure that is correct? Also you can use `/bin/tomcat10w.exe` to set java options

Comment: Yes, I need to set jasypt.encryptor.password before the app is UP because If this property is not set, the app throws an exception and don't start up. I tried to set this property in the /bin/setenv.bat like: set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djasypt.encryptor.password="secret" and don't works.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from the password value; this might have unexpected effects on the parsing of the environment variable.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. I tried to set with doble quote or simple quote or nothing, all time I get the same result. The main problem is that I can't arrive to Override method configure, the application fails before, because I added a log.debug before the line return application.sources(App.class); and don't see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the end was to create the file setenv.bat in ${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin/setenv.bat

Following the approach: [How to pass the -D additional parameter while starting tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984256/how-to-pass-the-d-additional-parameter-while-starting-tomcat)

The content of setenv.bat:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS -Djasypt.encryptor.password="secret"
```